# Armadillo complex sparse matrix inverse

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, armadillo, matrix-inverse

I'm writing a program with Armadillo C++ (4.400.1)

I have a matrix that has to be sparse and complex, and I want to calculate the inverse of such matrix. Since it is sparse it could be the pseudoinverse, but I can guarantee that the matrix has the full diagonal.

In the API documentation of Armadillo, it mentions the method `.i()` to calculate the inverse of any matrix, but `sp_cx_mat` members do not contain such method, and the `inv()` or `pinv()` functions cannot handle the `sp_cx_mat`  type apparently.

```
sp_cx_mat Y;

/*Fill Y ensuring that the diagonal is full*/

sp_cx_mat Z = Y.i();
```

or

```
sp_cx_mat Z = inv(Y);
```

None of them work.

I would like to know how to compute the inverse of matrices of `sp_cx_mat` type.

Comment: What are the dimensions? X * X or X * Y?

Comment: The matrix is square, so X by X

Comment: The inverse of a sparse matrix is not necessarily sparse. Do you really need the inverse of a sparse matrix? All literature I've seen after a quick search recommends to solve the underlying problem in a different way. I.e. use iterative methods (or others) to solve Ax = b.

Comment: You could compute the SVD. Let `U S V == Y`, then `Y.pinv() == U S.pinv() V`. Because the Y is of full-rank (because of that diagonal) `Armadillo::svd_econ()` doesn't make sense. So, computing the SVD will be significantly slower than other methods for solving the pseodo-inverse.

Comment: Yes, I need the inverse, because that inverted matrix will be used for the solution of (A^-1)x=b systems. Not calculating the inverted matrix would make me reformulate all the electrical models that fill the initial non-inverted matrix.

Comment: indeed Y.pinv() is nice, but it doesn't exist in the library for complex saparse matrices.

Comment: If you want to solve (A^-1)x=b, why don't you solve x=Ab instead?

Comment: Because, some items in x and b are missing, therefore the system is solved using newton raphson methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sparse matrix support in Armadillo is not complete and many of the factorizations/complex operations that are available for dense matrices are not available for sparse matrices.  There are a number of reasons for this, the largest being that efficient complex operations such as factorizations for sparse matrices is still very much an open research field.  So, there is no `.i()` function available for `cx_sp_mat` or other `sp_mat` types.  Another reason for this is lack of time on the part of the sparse matrix developers (...which includes me).

Given that the inverse of a sparse matrix is generally going to be dense, then you may simply be better off turning your `cx_sp_mat` into a `cx_mat` and then using the same inversion techniques that you normally would for dense matrices.  Since you are planning to represent this as a dense matrix anyway, then it's a fair assumption that you have enough RAM to do that.